# Kotlin coroutines handle error and implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

Using coroutines for the first time. Need help.

Here is my flow:

Presenter wants to login so calls Repository Interface. Repository implements RepositoryInterface.
So Repository calls APIInterface. APIInterface is implemented by APIInterfaceImpl. 
The APIInterfaceImpl finally calls the MyRetrofitInterface.

Here is the flow diagrammatically:

Presenter -> Repository -> APIInterfaceImpl -> MyRetrofitInterface

Once I get login response:

APIInterfaceImpl -> Repository -> Stores the data in cache -> Gives http status code to Presenter

Here is my code:

RepositoryInterface.kt

```
fun onUserLogin(loginRequest: LoginRequest): LoginResponse
```

Repository.kt

```
class Repository : RepositoryInterface {
   private var apiInterface: APIInterface? = null

   override fun onUserLogin(loginRequest: LoginRequest): LoginResponse {
         return apiInterface?.makeLoginCall(loginRequest)
   }
}
```

APIInterface.kt

```
suspend fun makeLoginCall(loginRequest): LoginResponse?
```

APIInterfaceImpl.kt

```
override suspend fun makeLoginCall(loginRequest: LoginRequest): LoginResponse? {
        if (isInternetPresent(context)) {
            try {
                val response = MyRetrofitInterface?.loginRequest(loginRequest)?.await()
                return response
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                //How do i return a status code here
            }
        } else {
        //How do i return no internet here
            return Exception(Constants.NO_INTERNET)
        }
}
```

MyRetrofitInterface.kt

```
@POST("login/....")
fun loginRequest(@Body loginRequest: LoginRequest): Deferred<LoginResponse>?
```

My questions are:

1. Is my approach architecturally right?
2. How do I pass http error codes or no internet connection in my code
3. Any more nicer approach to my solution?

Comment: where and how do you start a coroutine?

Comment: Yeah thats my problem...Can you please tell me how and where could i do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a good practice to launch a coroutine in a local scope which can be implemented in a lifecycle aware classes, for example **Presenter** or **ViewModel**. You can use next approach to pass data:

1. Create `sealed` `Result` class and its inheritors in separate file:

   ```
   sealed class Result<out T : Any>
   class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
   class Error(val exception: Throwable, val message: String = exception.localizedMessage) : Result<Nothing>()
   ```
2. Make `onUserLogin` function suspendable and returning `Result` in `RepositoryInterface` and `Repository`:

   ```
   suspend fun onUserLogin(loginRequest: LoginRequest): Result<LoginResponse> {
       return apiInterface.makeLoginCall(loginRequest)
   }
   ```
3. Change `makeLoginCall` function in `APIInterface` and `APIInterfaceImpl` according to the following code:

   ```
   suspend fun makeLoginCall(loginRequest: LoginRequest): Result<LoginResponse> {
       if (isInternetPresent()) {
           try {
               val response = MyRetrofitInterface?.loginRequest(loginRequest)?.await()
               return Success(response)
           } catch (e: Exception) {
               return Error(e)
           }
       } else {
           return Error(Exception(Constants.NO_INTERNET))
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use next code for your `Presenter`:

   ```
   class Presenter(private val repo: RepositoryInterface,
                   private val uiContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main
   ) : CoroutineScope { // creating local scope

       private var job: Job = Job()

       // To use Dispatchers.Main (CoroutineDispatcher - runs and schedules coroutines) in Android add
       // implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'
       override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
           get() = uiContext + job

       fun detachView() {
           // cancel the job when view is detached
           job.cancel()
       }

       fun login() = launch { // launching a coroutine
           val request = LoginRequest()
           val result = repo.onUserLogin(request) // onUserLogin() function isn't blocking the Main Thread

           //use result, make UI updates
           when (result) {
               is Success<LoginResponse> -> { /* update UI when login success */ } 
               is Error -> { /* update UI when login error */ }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**EDIT**

We can use extension functions on `Result` class to replace `when` expression:

```
inline fun <T : Any> Result<T>.onSuccess(action: (T) -> Unit): Result<T> {
    if (this is Success) action(data)
    return this
}
inline fun <T : Any> Result<T>.onError(action: (Error) -> Unit): Result<T> {
    if (this is Error) action(this)
    return this
}

class Presenter(...) : CoroutineScope {

    // ...

    fun login() = launch {
        val request = LoginRequest()
        val result = repo.onUserLogin(request) 

        result
            .onSuccess {/* update UI when login success */ }
            .onError { /* update UI when login error */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the example... can you please show me the code for repository and what should MyRetrofitInterface return? A Deferred or Result?

Comment: `MyRetrofitInterface` is the same as in your code. Added Repository code to my answer

Comment: Thank you...just a last question in my repository, I need to store the body of apiInterface.makeLoginCall(loginRequest). Since it returns a result, how could I get the body of it?

Comment: You can do it like this: `if (result is Success<LoginResponse>) {
            val response = result.data
        }`

Comment: @Sergey `login function isn't blocking the Main Thread when it is marked as 'suspend'` this is not true. suspending functions don't magically turn blocking code to unblocking code. In your example, the call to `repo.onUserLogin(request)` will block the main thread. In order to avoid it, you have to use a non-Main dispatcher. Since this is a web request, the recommended dispatcher is `Dispatchers.IO`. To change dispatcher, you should wrap the call with `val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { repo.onUserLogin(request) }`.

Comment: in `makeLoginCall` function there is a call to `MyRetrofitInterface?.loginRequest(loginRequest)?.await()`, so it is already running on another thread and no need to use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`. `MyRetrofitInterface?.loginRequest(loginRequest)?` returns a Deferred object, usually its used with `await` suspending function in order to wait for the result without blocking the `main/current thread`. @NimrodDayan I've edited comment a little bit to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: `Deferred` type and its `await()` method is used for concurrency. By itself, it does not provide any means to "wait for the result without blocking". For example, `async { Thread.sleep(5000L) }` if run in the context of the Main dispatcher, will block the main thread! The only reason `repo.onUserLogin(request)` in your code won't block the main thread is because as you said Retrofit internally manages worker threads for the enqueued requests. But this is an implementation detail of Retrofit. It does not mean that any API that returns Deferred will do the same and that's what emphasizing here.

Comment: I am trying this pattern but when an error occurs it does not go into the is Error -> block even though the debugger is saying its an error $result =  {Error@10966}

Comment: Thanks! What is `LoginRequest`?

Comment: I think it's some kind of data object, containing request information, e.g. email and password.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:**

I am trying this solution in my new app and i released that if an error occurs in launchSafe method and try to retry request, launcSafe() method does not work correctly. So i changed the logic like this and problem is fixed.

```
fun CoroutineScope.launchSafe(
    onError: (Throwable) -> Unit = {},
    onSuccess: suspend () -> Unit
) {
   launch {
        try {
            onSuccess()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            onError(e)
        }
    }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

I think a lot about this topic and came with a solution. I think this solution cleaner and easy to handle exceptions. First of all when use write code like

```
fun getNames() = launch { }
```

You are returning job instance to ui i think this is not correct. Ui should not have reference to job instance. I tried below solution it's working good for me. But i want to discuss if any side effect can occur. Appreciate to see your comments.

```
fun main() {


    Presenter().getNames()

    Thread.sleep(1000000)

}


class Presenter(private val repository: Repository = Repository()) : CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Default // Can be Dispatchers.Main in Android

    fun getNames() = launchSafe(::handleLoginError) {
        println(repository.getNames())
    }
    

    private fun handleLoginError(throwable: Throwable) {
        println(throwable)
    }

    fun detach() = this.cancel()

}

class Repository {

    suspend fun getNames() = suspendCancellableCoroutine<List<String>> {
        val timer = Timer()

        it.invokeOnCancellation {
            timer.cancel()
        }

        timer.schedule(timerTask {
            it.resumeWithException(IllegalArgumentException())
            //it.resume(listOf("a", "b", "c", "d"))
        }, 500)
    }
}


fun CoroutineScope.launchSafe(
    onError: (Throwable) -> Unit = {},
    onSuccess: suspend () -> Unit
) {
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        onError(throwable)
    }

    launch(handler) {
        onSuccess()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you moved from `CoroutineExceptionHandler` to `try-catch`?

Comment: Yes i moved, you should move definetly. Because first approach not best.

Comment: Thank you! I have been using `try-catch` for 2 years. I thought, `CoroutineExceptionHandler` would be better.

Comment: This is a good variant, but I found that we cannot get a right class name, method name, line number of a calling method. In `try-catch` we can invoke `Thread.currentThread().stackTrace[2]` and get line number of a crash line, but not of a calling class, but a class where `CoroutineScope.launchSafe` is written in. I mean, if we write this extension inside `MyLaunch.kt`, then in `try-catch` we will get `MyLaunch.launchSafe:10`, not `SomeFragment.loadItems:120`.

Comment: To overcome this behaviour, you can use `inline` modifier with `crossinline` and `noinline` modifiers. In this case we can capture a calling method, but not it's line number.

Comment: Thanks that's a good point to debug properly. I will try it.

Comment: Good luck! I will later write a similar solution in another topic! Thanks!